# relation between radius of convergence of Grand canonical partition function and Canonical partition function

Tags: physics, convergence

I want to show that the radius of convergence of Grand canonical partition function shows the exponential behavior of Canonical partition function.
I do this:
[image: In this picture I find radius of convergence for Grand canonical partition function. But in the end I can't understand concept that I need.]

In this picture I find radius of convergence for Grand canonical partition function. But in the end I can't understand concept that I need.